# Python using a for loop to import data from a text file?

Tags: python, numpy

I am importing many values from a text document that I have placed values in from another code in my personal python library. In the code that follows I am trying to import the data, but for some reason this for loop will not get the job done.  My output screen displays that I have a type error exclaiming that "int is not iterable".

```
import numpy as np

A = np.zeros([3,200000,50])
for i in range(50):
 A[0,:,i] = np.loadtxt("File Location",usecols=(i),unpack = True)
 A[1,:,i] = np.loadtxt("File Location",usecols=(i),unpack = True)
 A[2,:,i] = np.loadtxt("File Location",usecols=(i),unpack = True)
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback. Also this looks very wrong. Just load the entire file, then slice out the columns you need

Comment: Why are you wrapping `i` in parentheses here? `usecols=(i)`

Comment: Because the columns are recognized as a list.  I just figured out what I did wrong.

Comment: Since it handles it as a list I had to put a comma after the i.  That fixed the problem.  Sorry for wasting your time guys.